# PHP Appending a link to a string

Tags: php

I am trying to add a "Read More" system on my site and right now I have the text stopping after 150 words, but I can't seem to get the link right at all.

This is what I have at the end of my shortening loop:

```
$string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="posts.php?id='.$post['post_id'].'>Read More</a>';
```

When I look at my site the link points to this:

```
/posts.php?id=7%3ERead%20More%3C/a%3E...%3C/div%3E%3Cp%3EPosted%20on:%2030-09-14%2003:55:08in%20%3Ca%20href=
```

Its basically taking everything that comes after this (date and stuff) and putting it in my URL for some reason. If I just echo the `post['post_id']` by itself I am getting the correct output. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: show the surrounding code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the link and add this missing closing double quotations on the markup:

```
$stringCut = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddddddddddddadddddr ffff';
$post['post_id'] = 1;
$string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="posts.php?id='.$post['post_id'].'">Read More</a>';
                                                                                                        ^^
echo $string;
```

[Without closing quotes](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pnBDxy) 
[With closing quotes](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WjZmoG)